# Trying to load a div from one site and display it on another with jQuery, nothing showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, load

as the title says I need to show a div from one website on another. I've created a small test below that afaik should work using jQuery's .load, but when I open it up nothing shows. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
</head>
<body>
<script>
$('#transaction-section'.load('ajax/http://warburgrealty.com/agent/AGENT-69db6245d34d32e69208161ebcc412fe/samantha-frith #past-transactions-section');
</script>
<div id="transaction-section"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of things going on.

First, the syntax isn't quite right.  I would also move the JavaScript after the div definition.

```
<div id="transaction-section"></div>
<script>
$('#transaction-section').load('http://warburgrealty.com/agent/AGENT-69db6245d34d32e69208161ebcc412fe/samantha-frith');
</script>
```

Secondly, unless you are running this code on warburgrealty.com, you are going to run into a cross-origin request error.

You can read more about cross-origin resource sharing here: https://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I see, so you're saying this isn't possible unless the origin site enables it? Damn. Is there any other way that you know of other than just adjusting an iframe a bunch?

Comment: Are you able to write code on the backend?  From the server side, you could use something like curl or wget to fetch the page and parse it.  Or in PHP, file_get_contents() might do the trick.

Comment: I'm using Squarespace, so I have access to HTML. I might be able to use PHP somehow.. I'll have to do some research into that. Thank you for the advice! Accepted